# R leaflet addmarkers argument value for popup

Tags: r, leaflet

```
m <- leaflet() %>% 
addPolygons(data = SP) %>%
addTiles()
for(k in 1:nrow(rfcCleaned))
{
 lat = rfcCleaned$Latitude[k]
 long = rfcCleaned$Longitude[k]
 addMarkers(m, lng, lat, popup = as.character(k))  
}
m
```

addMarkers does not print any pop-ups. I even tried format(k) in place of as.character(k)). For the following code a single pop-up is displayed as expected. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
m <- leaflet() %>%
addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")
m  # Print the map
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have any sample data

Comment: @PPC

Latitude
18.73605
18.73605
18.73605
18.7465
18.7465
18.7465
18.7465
18.73209
18.73209
18.73209

Longitude
73.53296
73.53296
73.53296
73.6281
73.6281
73.6281
73.6281
73.63924
73.63924
73.63924

You can use this data

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have already done that but since my stackoverflow score is pretty low it won't be visible is the message I got.

Answer (score 1):

To add markers it is not required to bind them in loop. You can simply add them to piped command after tiles.

Here is the sample data i have used to display markers.

```
       id   slon   slat
        2 93.089 25.054
        3 93.038 24.939
        4 92.988 24.825
        5 92.937 24.710
        6 92.886 24.596
        7 92.835 24.482
```

R query

`library(leaflet)
ex1map<-leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(ex1map, lat = ex1$slat,lng = ex1$slon,popup = as.character(ex1$id))`

In the below picture i am able to see popup of their respective id.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @PPC, I guess addmarkers does not work in a for loop. I forgot that R considers every variable as a vector, that is why used the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you don't want to add another column of id, here is another alternative solution.

data ex2 has records provided by you in above comments.

`ex2map <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(ex2, lat = ex2$Latitude,lng = ex2$Longitude,popup = as.character(1:nrow(ex2)))`

Note: your data has duplicate records,so popups will be displayed for the last duplicate record found